# Selecting Dropdown fields with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I am using the record and play option to record test scripts in my web app. I want to know the command that will be appropriate to use to enable me to click on a dropdown and select and  verify an element in the dropdown. Anyone knows how do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use select.

select ( selectLocator,optionLocator )
Select an option from a drop-down using an option locator.
Option locators provide different ways of specifying options of an HTML Select element (e.g. for selecting a specific option, or for asserting that the selected option satisfies a specification). There are several forms of Select Option Locator.

Regards,

Tarun Gupta